receiving-error ERROR NullInjectorError:R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[markdownEditorConfig ->markdownEditorConfig ->markdownEditorConfig]
i am working on the angular cli 18 and want to implement angular-markdown-editor and  I have followed the instructions on this link https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-markdown-editorafter all the steps and running ng-serve I kept getting the error as shown in the picture.error in browser console
also if i am remove the bootstrap style in the angular.json than ui is like 
and if i am not remove the bootstrap style in the angular.json than ui is like  so i want this ui without including bootstrap style in angular.json
also
// src/app/app.module.ts

import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Injectable, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { from, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularMarkdownEditorModule } from 'angular-markdown-editor';

@Injectable()
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    TranslateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    L10nTranslationModule.forRoot(l10nConfig, {
      translationLoader: TranslationLoader,
    }),
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 3000,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
      newestOnTop: false,
      progressBar: true,
    }),
    AngularMarkdownEditorModule.forRoot({ iconlibrary: 'fa' })
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initL10n,
      deps: [L10nLoader],
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private translationService: L10nTranslationService) {
    const savedLanguage = localStorage.getItem('language') || 'en-US';
    this.translationService.setLocale({ language: savedLanguage });
  }
}


and this is config file also
import { ApplicationConfig, provideZoneChangeDetection } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideToastr } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { provideNoopAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslationLoader } from './app.module';
import { l10nConfig } from './l10n-config';
import { provideL10nIntl, provideL10nTranslation } from 'angular-l10n';
import { AngularMarkdownEditorModule } from 'angular-markdown-editor';


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideToastr(),
    provideNoopAnimations(),
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideL10nTranslation(l10nConfig, {
      translationLoader: TranslationLoader,
    }),
    provideL10nIntl(),
    AngularMarkdownEditorModule,
  ],
};


and this is app componenent .ts and
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  Router,
  RouterLink,
  RouterOutlet,
  NavigationEnd
} from '@angular/router';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
;
import { AngularMarkdownEditorModule } from 'angular-markdown-editor';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, CommonModule , AngularMarkdownEditorModule , FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = ''
}


here is html file
  <angular-markdown-editor
  textareaId="editor1"
  >
</angular-markdown-editor>

i want to show the result like this https://ghiscoding.github.io/angular-markdown-editor/#/reactive-editor
but getting error what is the issue in config file

Just adding the AngularMarkdownEditorModule to the providers array does not add the providers. We need to use the same method as seen in the original code using forRoot to import the providers, this will ensure that markdownEditorConfig is made available for the service to use.

You can use importProvidersFrom to add the providers. But I think it is not needed, you can try two approaches.
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    ...
    AngularMarkdownEditorModule.forRoot({ iconlibrary: 'fa' })
  ],
};

OR
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    ...
    importProvidersFrom(AngularMarkdownEditorModule.forRoot({ iconlibrary: 'fa' })),
  ],
};


Hello @Naren murali  i am working on one project which is use tailwind and here this package is globally use the bootstrap  so it is generate conflict related to the style and if i am remove bootstrap style in angular.json than it is affect to the angular markdown-editor how to resolve this style related issue

@Rinkal you can try :host ::ng-deep { .. add imports here } you need to add this to the component scss file, then the styles will apply only for one component, so it will not conflict with tailwind

sorry @Naren Murali  I don't have much experience in Angular I don't know what you mean  i I edit  the question so that you get an idea where the problem

@Rinkal please create a new question so that I can view only the details related to this new issue

Hello Naren Murali  i am create a new question can you please review this question ?

@Rinkal please share the question here

@ Naren Murali
markdown question 

@Rinkal this is a complex issue that I need a working example to check, either in stackblitz or github repo!

yes @ Naren Murali   markdown editor preview issue
[ demo markdown] (https://github.com/Rinkal-2024/markdown-editor)
